# Index has bad entries at data rows

Tags: r, datetime, zoo

I have a csv file of 11 stations from 2008 to 2019 i would like to read it as a zoo object. when I select the column as 1:2 i get erros as bellow.

```
kunduz <- read.zoo("data_ALLLL.csv", header=TRUE, index.column = 1:2,
                   format="%m/%d/%Y", tz="UTC ")


Error in read.zoo("data_ALLLL.csv",
    header = TRUE, index.column = 0, format = "%m/%d/%Y",  :    index has
    46882 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
    17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
```

when I change 1:2 to 1:3 I am getting this error

```
Error in \`[.data.frame\`(rval, , j) : undefined columns selected.
```

Could you please help me to read this file as zoo object.

Comment: Question need to have sufficient information that responders can reproduce the problem.  That is not possible since the question did not include the input.  Please read the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.